# In Oracle, what dictionary table tells me the "store in" value for partitioned indexes?

Tags: oracle, data-structures, plsql, indexing, metadata

We are running Oracle 11g and have some partitioned tables. I am trying to write an automated process to script out the indexes on these tables. (Basically when we do bulk loads, we want to drop all the indexes beforehand and recreate them afterward.)

The problem I have is knowing how to script out the partitioned indexes. Some are created with "LOCAL STORE IN (tablespacename)" and others just with "LOCAL" (which stores index extents in the same partition as the data). In either case, dba_indexes.tablespace_name is null, and I have having a heck of a time scripting out the two different cases correctly.

1. I know I can simply re-run the original DDL to recreate the indexes, but multiple parts of the organization can make changes, and there would be less risk if the loader tool could be self-contained and simply rebuild whatever was there to begin with.
2. I can query dba_ind_subpartitions, and if the tablespace_name values for every subpartition all match, then I can assume/infer that I should STORE IN that tablespace name. But, if the table is in a small single-partition state (e.g. newly created or just after archival), then the ones created with just LOCAL also match this test, so this is also not a perfect way of telling them apart.
3. I can compare the names of the index subpartition tablespaces to the data table partition tablespaces, and if they match, then I can assume/infer that those should be created with just LOCAL. But, that drags a bunch of extra tables into my query and makes it really hard to read, so I am worried about maintainability going forward. Plus, it just seems like a kludge.

It seems like there should be someplace in Oracle's data dictionaries where it is simply keeping track of this, and where I can just directly look it up instead of having to do a bunch of math and rely on assumptions. But, I have done a good deal of digging and haven't yet found it. So, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#ARPLS66885) is easier than querying the data dictionary:

```
--Sample table and index.
create table test1(a number);
create index test1_idx on test1(a);

--Store the DDL, drop the index, then re-create it.
declare
    ddl_before clob;
begin
    ddl_before := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', 'TEST1_IDX');

    execute immediate 'drop index test1_idx';

    --Do some processing here.

    execute immediate ddl_before;
end;
/
```

Comment: On first attempt, I got `object "indexname" of type INDEX not found in schema "SYSTEM"`. Solution was to include the additional "schema" param, like this: `ddl_before := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('INDEX', 'TEST1_IDX', 'SCHEMA_NAME');`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as jonearles describes, the dbms_metadata package is the way to generate DDL for existing objects.

But, it seems to me, this is more work than is required for what you're trying to achieve.  If this is all for loading data, I recommend you simply alter the indexes to be unusable, set 'skip_unusable_indexes=true', do the data load, and the rebuild the indexes.

This should achieve what you want, without having to drop and re-create the indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Although an insert alone is faster without the presence of indexes, have you benchmarked a load into tables with indexes enabled and established that it is slower than disabling (more robust than dropping!) and rebuilding them?

When you direct path insert into a table with indexes, Oracle optimises the index maintenance process by creating temporary segments to hold just the data required for the index builds. This generally allows the index maintenance to scan much smaller segments than otherwise required -- the temp segments plus the existing indexes.